Movie about a boy who burns in a house and haunts his parents probably a 90s movie
I'm looking for a movie which was probably filmed in the 90s.
The plot is about a boy (named Kevin I think) who died in a house fire. As I can remember, he blames his mother for his death or something like that, and he haunts her (or more accurately both his parents).
Then the parents find a secret room, and they start discovering things. At the end of the movie, the mom walks into a burning house to make peace with her son (or somethng like that).
That's all I can remember. If anyone can help, please do. I've been searching for this film for quite a long time now.
